# how to get values from SqlDataReader to forloop execution?

Tags: c#-4.0

Here I coding for get each and every StudyUID(as string) from database to SqlDataReader,but i need to know how the reader value call to forloop execution.
Get to read each and every StudyUID for execution.Here is the code :.

```
 public void automaticreport()
    {
        //string autsdyid="";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        con.Open();
        string autoquery = "Select StudyUID From StudyTable Where status='2'";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(autoquery, con);
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        for()
        {
            //how to call each StudyUId from database through for loop

        if (!this.reportchk)
        {
            Reportnew cf = new Reportnew();
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((WaitCallback)(o => cf.ReportRetrive(this, autsdyid, true)));
        }
        else
        {
            int num = (int)System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Reports checking in progress, Please wait sometime and try again later", "OPTICS", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
        }

        con.Close();
    }
```

Comment: normally:  while (rdr.Read())

Comment: but while loop get all values ,i need each and everyone to check,for that using forloop

Comment: I don't understand. rdr.Read() gets the next row -- so inside the while you can do rdr["StudyUId"] for each value

Comment: i get already through while.i need each studuid to check whether reported or not like that forloop is must

Comment: while loop is checking for true only,i need mot like that

Comment: just i need how to get the SQLDATAREADEr to forloop

Comment: @Rob:How to get SQLDATAREADER value to forloop only,that am needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @R.T and others have mentioned you can use the `Read` method on the data reader. Looking at your sample code you might want to refactor it slightly to meet more of the SOLID principles and make sure you're not leaking database connections

Here's an example of code that has been refactored a bit.

```
public void automaticreport()
{
    foreach (var autsdyid in LoadStudyIdentifiers())
    {
        if (!this.reportchk)
        {
            Reportnew cf = new Reportnew();
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((WaitCallback)(o => cf.ReportRetrive(this, autsdyid, true)));
        }
        else
        {
            int num = (int)System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Reports checking in progress, Please wait sometime and try again later", "OPTICS", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
        }
    }
}

private string[] LoadStudyIdentifiers()
{
    var results = new List<string>();

    // adding a using statement will close the database connection if there are any errors
    // avoiding consuming the database connection pool 
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(constr)) 
    {
        conn.Open();
        var autoquery = "Select StudyUID From StudyTable Where status='2'";

        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(autoquery, con)) 
        {
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while(rdr.Read())
            {
                results.Add(rdr.GetString(rdr.GetOrdinal("StudyUID")));
            }
        }
    }

    return results.ToArray();
}
```

Note: I wrote this in notepad so there is no guarantee it will compile but should give an indication as to how you could refactor your code.

Comment: Is it Check each and every StudyUID for report?

Comment: @Ramji21 I'm not 100% sure what you are asking? If you are asking will this return all of the `StudyUID` records from the `StudyTable` and add them to the thread pool queue then the answer is yes.

Comment: ur code is right,but showing error in var results = new IList<string>()

Comment: @Ramji21 it should have been = new List<string>() not the IList interface. I have updated my answer

Comment: Thanks Sir,I want to compile,plz wait Sir

Comment: Itz working,thanking You Sir,Help me alot,Am actually stuck here,thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

```
if (rdr.HasRows)
{
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
         Console.WriteLine(rdr.getString("columnName"));
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot access it via name, either use `rdr.GetString(0)` or ``rdr.GetString(rdr.GetOrdinal("StudyUID"))``

Comment: hmm... i see my edited answer.. with Console.WriteLine(rdr.getString("columnName"));

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `while` loop like this:

```
while (rdr.Read())
{
  string s = rdr.GetString(rdr.GetOrdinal("Column"));
//Apply logic to retrieve here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    string value = reader.getString("columnName");
}
```